# Watir-webdriver send the request twice in IE11 on Windows8.1

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am currently writting a test which activates an user account by going to an activation url mentioned in an email.

I ran the test on chrome and firefox and it works fine. When I copy pasted the link in IE manually it works fine.

But when I do the same from the test script in IE, it seems like the request is sent twice.

```
 @browser.goto(url)
```

I can see that a dialog appears saying the account is activated successfully and within a second another dialog appears automatically saying that the activation link has been used already.

How can I fix this problem?

I am using IE11 with Windows8.1.

Latest watirwebdriver, selenium webdrivers and IEdriver are installed.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Show us your code, else we would just be playing a guessing game.

Comment: Have added it now. Thanks.